# Block BackKeyPress on RootFrame not working Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Lately I ran into another issue which is hard to grasp for me. On msdn(http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202868%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) we read :

```
Also, the BackKeyPress event is available in the PhoneApplicationFrame class. The frame can handle the event directly before the active page receives it and the key press can be canceled
```

According to this I wrote a straightforward example :

```
private void InitializePhoneApplication()
    {
        if (phoneApplicationInitialized)
            return;

        // Create the frame but don't set it as RootVisual yet; this allows the splash
        // screen to remain active until the application is ready to render.
        RootFrame = new PhoneApplicationFrame();
        RootFrame.Navigated += CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;
        RootFrame.BackKeyPress += App_BackKeyPress;
        // Handle navigation failures
        RootFrame.NavigationFailed += RootFrame_NavigationFailed;

        // Ensure we don't initialize again
        phoneApplicationInitialized = true;

    }

    void App_BackKeyPress(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("1");
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

And in MainClass I added code below to find out whether it is really stopped

```
        public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BackKeyPress += MainPage_BackKeyPress;
    }

    void MainPage_BackKeyPress(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("2");
    }
```

To my disappoinment, output displays "1 2" so what is wrong what it is not suppressing key execution?

Comment: And what happens if in your `void MainPage_BackKeyPress(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)` you put: `if (!e.Handeled) Debug.WriteLine("2");`?

Comment: e.Handled does not exists

Comment: Nah, not this :) - it should be `if (!e.Cancel) Debug.WriteLine("2");`

Comment: Does not display anything, e.Cancel is then set to false.

Comment: I deleted my answer as it turned out to be useless. Along with the answer your comments below it were also deteled (without answer they will be also useless and misleading).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across similar problem, Windows Phone can only cancel going back execution when there is something to go back, I mean any PhoneApplicationPage. I guess you press Go Back button on your first page and therefore WP has nothing to back up. On your page add button directing to another page and on this page press Go Back to find out whether execution is suppressed.